# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'paddingBottom' with value '@dimen/ activity_vertical_margin')

Tags: android

I was trying to build a navigation drawer for which I copied code from some website and I am getting this error in one of the XMLs.

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'paddingBottom' with value '@dimen/
>    activity_vertical_margin')

How to get rid of this error?

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TabbedActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you copied the `dimens.xml` file too.

Comment: the tutorial was a bit less clear. Added dimens.xml now. Worked fine.
thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to Android view of the project
2. go to app -> res -> values.
3. Right click on values
4. Then "New" (right at the top of the pop-up menu), "Value resource file".
5. In the "file name" space, type "dimens.xml" (without the quotation marks " ")
6. Then simply "Ok".

Click on the newly created "dimens.xml" file. Remove all code in it and paste the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">8dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

that's should work

Answer (score 1):

In some project templates you find `app/src/main/res/values/dimens.xml` with only one value:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

So you need to add the missing ones to that file:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Hope this helps.