# How to send data in JSON format to Back end using Retrofit

Tags: android

I am creating a food booking App in Android.I need to send my order details which includes multiple product details and user details to back end which is created in P H P.I am using retrofit for web service calling.How to send these data in Json format to back end  using retrofit.Do i need to create model class for saving data.

Comment: what have you  tried ?

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180957/send-post-request-with-params-using-retrofit

Comment: stuck on confirm order page, the page has product details

Comment: *"Do i need to create model class for saving data"* depends on what is your response data

Answer (score 1):

In API Interface

```
@Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
@POST("auth/login")
Call<String> login(@Body RequestBody requestBody);
```

and when you make service call

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put(Constants.Params.EMAIL, etEmail.getText().toString());
        jsonObject.put(Constants.Params.PASS_WORD, etPassword.getText().toString());


    } catch (JSONException e) {

    }

    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    final Call<String> loginCall = apiInterface.login(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), jsonObject.toString));
```