# How To Post using Retrofit Android Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, post, retrofit

I Have JSON like this and i want to post this data using retrofit android

{
"status": "",
"message": "",
"data": {
"request": {
"textData": "123"
}
}
}

and i don't know how to post this data, does anyone want to help me answer it?

Comment: you can make pojo class for the request and pass it as body by annotating it with @Body in your API interface

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send Post Request with params using Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180957/send-post-request-with-params-using-retrofit)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating a POJO or data class (in kotlin) of your request which makes doing things like this easier.

**MyRequest.kt**

```
data class MyRequest(
    var status: String,
    var message: String,
    var data: MyData
)


data class MyData(
    var request: RequestData
)


data class RequestData(
    var textData: String
)
```

**MyApiInterface.kt**

```
interface MyApiInterface {
    @POST("/my_url_endpoint")
    fun myRequest(
        @Body request: MyRequest
    ): Call<Unit>
}
```

**MyActivity.kt**

```
....

val request = MyRequest(
    "Ok",
    "My Message",
    MyData(
        request = RequestData("Hello World")
    )
 )

RetrofitClient.api.myRequest(request).enqueue(object: Callback<Unit> {
  override fun onResponse(call: Call<Unit>, response: Response<Unit>) {
      // TODO: some task
  }

  override fun onFailure(call: Call<Unit>, t: Throwable) {
      // TODO: some task
  }
})

....
```

after doing this request if you have added logging interceptor you can check that request being made with following body.

> {"data":{"request":{"textData":"Hello World"}},"message":"My Message","status":"Ok"}