# My first android app and nothing showing up on smart phone's screen

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started developing android applications and now I have a problem.
I modified my smart phone to developer mode and I also checked USB debugging . Android Studio also can recognize my smart phone but when I select it at "Selecting Deployment Target" , nothing is showing up at my smart phone . And in android studio this message starts to show up:
Process 'command 'D:\Programming\Android\sdk-tools-windows-4333796\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Can anyone help me with this ?
Best

Comment: Are you able to run your application on emulator? if not try installing sdk components by running sdk manager. Restart android studio and try again.

Comment: I just found out the solution for my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005048/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-paddingbottom-with-value-d

Answer (score 0):

Some smartphones like Samsung, LG, Quantum, Motorolla, Asus (among others) need a driver that can be downloaded from the PlayStore to work properly the emulation of an .apk via development tool.

But others

Some motorola smarthphones need external software for this as well. (As is the case with some Moto G)

for example: driver for moto G 
https://support.motorola.com/in/en/drivers